# How to use ip6tables's function to defragment ipv6 fragment packet?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I'm using following ip6tables commnds to accept ipv6 packet,
`ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT`

However if the target packet is fragmented pakcet, only the first fragment can be receive, other fragment ipv6 packet would be drop. AFAIK, IPv4 fragmented packets would be reassembled before entering LOCAL_IN chain, So is there any commands to get the same result like iptables. BTW, The kernel version :3.4.39
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My kernel version is v3.4.39, after reading the source code, It turns out this version don't support reassemble IPv6 fragmented packet before entering netfilter local-in chains,
besides ipv6-conntrack module does reassemble fragments, but only conntrack module can use the assembled packet. I found a patch which fixed this:[***netfilter: push reasm skb through instead of original frag skbs ***]
 (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6aafeef03b9d9ecf255f3a80ed85ee070260e1ae)